Delay for memberSnapshot on LinkedIn API
I use the Member data portability API from LinkedIn and make snapshotmember api call. The data is far from realtime data. I want to retrieve ALL_likes but it's been more than 5 days that the output data doesn't change at all and show me last reactions from 5 days ago. Is it usual?
